# MSSQL Show rows with NULL value in Query with Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables.

`tbl1` looks like this:

```
CODE    Role    Sequence
0001    Role1   1
0002    Role2   2
0003    Role3   3
0004    Role4   4
0005    Role5   5
```

`tbl2` looks like this:

```
Code    RoleCode    User    DateFrom    DateTo
00002   0001        Usr1    2019-11-09  9998-12-31
00002   0002        Usr2    2019-11-09  9998-12-31
```

I want to join them like this which is I have already made:

```
tbl1.Code   tbl1.Role   tbl2.User   tbl2.DateFrom   tbl2.DateTo
0001        Role1       Usr1        2019-11-09      9998-12-31
0002        Role2       User2       2019-11-09      9998-12-31
0003        Role3       NULL        NULL            NULL
0004        Role4       NULL        NULL            NULL
0005        Role5       NULL        NULL            NULL
```

By doing this query:

```
SELECT  tbl1.Code,
        tbl1.Role,
        tbl2.User,
        tbl2.DateFrom,
        tbl2.DateTo
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.Code = tbl2.RoleCode
```

Question: How can I show all rows of `tbl1` when I put a where clause in my query like this:

```
SELECT  tbl1.Code,
        tbl1.Role,
        tbl2.User,
        tbl2.DateFrom,
        tbl2.DateTo
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.Code = tbl2.RoleCode
WHERE tbl2.Code = '00002'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a condition on a `left join`ed table in the `where` clause implicitly turns it to an `inner join`, and hence eliminates all records for which the `left join` did not match from the resultset.

You need to put the condition on the `left join`ed table in the `on` clause of the `join`:

```
SELECT  tbl1.Code,
        tbl1.Role,
        tbl2.User,
        tbl2.DateFrom,
        tbl2.DateTo
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.Code = tbl2.RoleCode AND tbl2.Code = '00002'
```

Comment: Great! it works! thanks for your help. have a nice day

Comment: Welcome @Glenn! Have a nice day too.